# CSS on hover effect not working

Tags: css

Why does the css :hover effect not work?
http://jsfiddle.net/t7on1k15/

```
    body,html
    {
        font-family: courier;
        height:100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #idDivBodyWrapper
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: lightgray;
    }

    #four:hover
    {
        color:black;
    }
```

The HTML

```
<div id="idDivBodyWrapper" style="vertical-align:middle;">
        <div style="position:absolute;display:block;float:left;left:0;Top:0"><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="opacity:1;background:transparent;font-family:courier;font-weight:bold;" onclick="location.href='http://vqplan.com';"><i style="color:white;opacity:1;" class="fa fa-th fa-fw fa-5x"></i><br><span style="opacity:1;color:white">home</span></button></div>

 <table style="width:100%;height:100%;background:black;clear:both;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;"><tr><td>
<h1 id="four" style="font-size:10vh;color:white;">Code that lasts.<br><br><i id="one" class="fa fa-terminal fa-3x fa-fw" style="color:white;"></i></h1>

</td></tr></table>
</div><!--end idDivBodyWrapper-->
```

Here is one that does work:
http://jsfiddle.net/tuxdukz4/

Comment: try removing the inline styling, and place that into your css.

Comment: great thank you for a quick answer guys. I don't know why anyone thinks that's a -1 question. It's a bizarre quirk of CSS that if an inline style color hasn't been specified then an internal CSS hover rule will be executed but if a color has been specified inline then it won't....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS - **CASCADING** style sheets. You've got `style="color:white"` inside your `h1#four` element. That `color:white` is at a higher precedence level than your external style sheet rule, so color: white overrides the :hover style.

If you mod your fiddle and put `color:purple` into the h1's `style=` attribute, you'll get the exact same behavior: the hover won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Because of CSS Specificity. I truly recommend you to read about it: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

You have an element-level style `color: white` that overrides the hover effect.

Check this for a working one: http://jsfiddle.net/t7on1k15/1/

Answer (score 0):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t7on1k15/2/

change the `<h1 id="four" style="font-size:10vh;color:white;">` html to this:

```
<h1 id="four">Code that lasts.<br><br></h1>
```

and then add this css:

```
#four {
    font-size:10vh;color:white;    
}
```

your inline style has highest precedence over other css code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that putting the style inline ("style="font-size:10vh;color:white;") takes precedence over css. Inline style has higher priority. You actually couldn't style #four without hover in css if you use an inline style.